# Как предсказать событие по имеющимся данным?

Tags: машинное-обучение, big-data

Как по имеющимся данным клиента предсказывать купит ли клиент страховку. Допустим страхование в сфере имущества - дома, квартиры. На основании датасета хотелось бы выделить ряд признаков и протестировать на валидационной выборке точность предсказания.

Comment: Закиньте всё фичи в рандом форест и радуйтесь. Нужна конкретная задача для конкретного ответа. В противном случае, ничего толкового сказать не получится.

Comment: Как уже сказал @hedgehogues, все будет очень сильно зависеть от ваших данных. Начните [отсюда - выберете метод(ы)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) и пробовать, пробовать, пробовать... ;)

Comment: Да и вообще, нужно ли Вам мл? Может вам достаточно десятка условий ифами... Мл же делают не от того, что это модно... или...